# Dynamic Where conditions with IIF and IsNull in SQL MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is it possible to write the WHERE clause with an IIF and an IsNull condition in SQL MS-ACCESS?
ie:

> > SELECT Table1.colx,....  FROM ((Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON
> > Table1.col1=Table2.col1)  INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.col2=Table2.col2)
> > WHERE
> > IIF(IsNull(Table1.colx='someValue1'),Table1.colx='someValue2',Table1.colx='someValue1')

Comment: While possible, the query doesn't make sense. If `Table1.colx='someValue1'` would be null, so would `Table1.colx='someValue2` and `Table1.colx='someValue1'`.

Comment: you are absolutely right, doesn't make sense. What I'm trying to do is if (TablTe1.colx='someValue1' AND Table1.colx='someValue2)=TRUE then take TablTe1.colx='someValue1' only, if (TablTe1.colx='someValue1' =FALSE AND Table1.colx='someValue2=TRUE) take Table1.colx='someValue2 only. but I connot get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much never want to use `IIF` in a `WHERE` clause. Just use `AND`, `OR`, and parentheses.

From your comment, the solution seems simple:

```
WHERE (TablTe1.colx='someValue1' AND Table1.colx='someValue2' AND TablTe1.colx='someValue1')
OR  ((TablTe1.colx <> 'someValue1' OR Table1.colx <> 'someValue2') AND  Table1.colx='someValue2')
```